# How to send notification to physically closer android devices

Tags: android, notifications

I have an idea of developing an Android App which has following requirement.

Say one user downloads my app from Playstore. After that i want that user to send notification  to other android devices closer to his position. This notification will include link to download my App from Playstore.

Please do let me know how to achieve this. I am new to android development.

Thanks,
Sandip Patel

Answer (score 0):

Why you try to do is more or less impossible.

A) you can't detect Android devices around you. It's also not desired by most people that you can see them / their phone.

B) You can't send notifications to random devices. That would be considered spam.

The only thing you could do:

Write an app that sends the user's location to a server of yours. That would give you a database of Android devices and their location. You can use that information to send notifications to all users of your app in an area. If you do that you have created an app that works roughly like [Google Latitude](https://www.google.com/latitude)